# How do I use an image for a project using PIL in Python code?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a blackjack game in Python using Tkinter and PIL packages. I saved all the necessary cards in a folder on my desktop but cannot seem to get the card images to appear.

Below is the code I have tried :

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.title("Blackjack")
canvas = Canvas(root, bg="green", height=1200, width=800)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(
"C:\Desktop\GUI\Images\Cards\2_of_clubs.png"))

root.mainloop()
```

How to make images appear when using tkinter ?

Comment: Right now you are creating a canvas and an image but not putting the image on the canvas. Add `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor="nw")` before the `mainloop`

Comment: Also you need to use *raw* string if you use single backslash in the path string.

Comment: I tried this and now am getting this error message...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2_of_clubs.png'

I have the images saved in a folder on my desktop. What is the proper way to name the file when trying to use the image?

Comment: It is better to update the question with what you have tried and post the full error traceback.

Comment: you have to escape the file path backslash with a backslash or use raw strings: `r""`, you do anything with the image

Comment: Did you actually mean to use a folder  called “Desktop” in the root of your C: drive or did you mean to go to your user folder and then Desktop?